# How to implement a dynamic bootstrap 4 accordion, using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm looking for a way to add a new bootstrap 4 accordion when I click on button. Anybody could you please help me on that? And moreover, code should be implemented in Jquery. That too, I don't know whether it is possible or not to add new accordion dynamically in jquery.

```js
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addAccordion').click( function() {
        var newDiv = "<div class='card'> <div class='card-header'> <a class='card-link' data-toggle='collapse' href='#collapseOne'>
        Collapsible Group Item #1</a>
        </div>
      <div id='collapseOne' class='collapse show' data-parent='#accordion'>
        <div class='card-body'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div> </div> </div>";
        $('.display').append(newDiv);
           
    });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
  </div>
  
    <div class="display"> </div>
    
     <button id="addAccordion">Add new accordion</button>
```

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your question and make it readable by adding punctuation (you know, commas, dots, etc.) If you are asking people for help, at least please take five minutes to write properly and ask a readable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this you can add dynamic accordion also open and close accordion dynamically

```js
let id = 0
$('#addAccordion').click(() => {
id++
       var test = "<div class='card'> <div class='card-header'> <a class='card-link' data-toggle='collapse' href='#collapse"+id+"'>" +
         "Collapsible Group Item "+id+"</a> </div> <div id='collapse"+id+"' class = 'collapse' data-parent = '#accordion' ><div class='card-body'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </div> </div> </div>";
       $('.display').append(test);
     });
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo">
        Collapsible Group Item #2
      </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          consectetur adipisicing 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
    <div class="display"> </div>
    
     <button id="addAccordion" type="button">Add new accordion</button>
```

please vote answer as a useful if this is a solution, thank you in advance.

Comment: thanks a lot for your correct answer to my question. but I made some change in my html code here basically  when I added more then four accordions since fourth accordion when I click on 3rd or 4th  accordion it is not working properly can you please have a look on my issue once.

Comment: here my concern is every accordion should open or close individually. basically first accordion must be in open status. 
       when I add second accordion as well if i am click on second accordion,  the first accordion should be close apart from that if I add third accordion as well if am click on third accordion , then second accordion will close like this. I request for could you please changes your like that once

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `backtick` instead of `inverted comma` actually there was syntax error where you define `var newDiv`

**Working Code:-**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
              $('#addAccordion').click( function() {
                  var newDiv = `<div class='card'> <div class='card-header'> <a class='card-link' data-toggle='collapse' href='#collapseOne'>
                  Collapsible Group Item #1</a>
                  </div>
                <div id='collapseOne' class='collapse show' data-parent='#accordion'>
                  <div class='card-body'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</div> </div> </div>`;
                  $('.display').append(newDiv);
              });
              });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


 <div id="accordion">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
              Collapsible Group Item #1
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo">
            Collapsible Group Item #2
          </a>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
              consectetur adipisicing 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      
        <div class="display"> </div>
        
         <button id="addAccordion">Add new accordion</button>
```